# Lenovo E320 is in airplane mode, says toggle hardware switch, but has no hardware switch and WiFi is still hard locked

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, bluetooth, debian-wheezy

Yesterday, my laptop (Lenovo E320) suddenly enabled "Airplane mode" after reboot, saying I should toggle my hardware switch to enable wifi (and bluetooth) again. The thing is I don't have such switch on my laptop.

I was running Debian testing when the problem first occured, and tried to reinstall the whole system on a brand new drive, but the problem persists. Wifi is enabled in BIOS.

I have followed several tutorials, mostly from askubuntu, but none of them worked for me.

- `rfkill unblock all` only fixes soft blocks
- power off, removing battery and bios reset do nothing
- reinstall (purge) `firmware-iwlwifi` package and restart doesn't work
- restart `network-manager` doesn't work
- adding "blacklist wmi" to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` doesn't work

Output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Output of `lspci -nn | grep 0280`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0084]
```

Output of `lsmod | grep iwl`:

```
iwlmvm                225280  0
iwldvm                143360  0
iwlwifi               147456  2 iwldvm,iwlmvm
mac80211              638976  2 iwldvm,iwlmvm
cfg80211              573440  4 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm,iwlmvm
```

`ifconfig` only lists `enp8s0` and `lo`, there used to be more output.

Output of `iw list`:

```
    Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 20
    max scan IEs length: 195 bytes
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
        * 00-0f-ac:10
        * GCMP (00-0f-ac:8)
        * 00-0f-ac:9
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * monitor
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x1072
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX Greenfield
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
        HT RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        TX unequal modulation not supported
        HT TX Max spatial streams: 1
        HT TX MCS rate indexes supported may differ
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
    Frequencies:
        * 2412 MHz [1] (14.0 dBm)
        * 2417 MHz [2] (14.0 dBm)
        * 2422 MHz [3] (14.0 dBm)
        * 2427 MHz [4] (14.0 dBm)
        * 2432 MHz [5] (14.0 dBm)
        * 2437 MHz [6] (14.0 dBm)
        * 2442 MHz [7] (14.0 dBm)
        * 2447 MHz [8] (14.0 dBm)
        * 2452 MHz [9] (14.0 dBm)
        * 2457 MHz [10] (14.0 dBm)
        * 2462 MHz [11] (14.0 dBm)
        * 2467 MHz [12] (14.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 2472 MHz [13] (14.0 dBm) (no IR)
Supported commands:
     * new_interface
     * set_interface
     * new_key
     * start_ap
     * new_station
     * new_mpath
     * set_mesh_config
     * set_bss
     * authenticate
     * associate
     * deauthenticate
     * disassociate
     * join_ibss
     * join_mesh
     * set_tx_bitrate_mask
     * frame
     * frame_wait_cancel
     * set_wiphy_netns
     * set_channel
     * set_wds_peer
     * probe_client
     * set_noack_map
     * register_beacons
     * start_p2p_device
     * set_mcast_rate
     * Unknown command (104)
     * connect
     * disconnect
Supported TX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
Supported RX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * managed: 0x40 0xd0
     * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
     * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
software interface modes (can always be added):
     * monitor
interface combinations are not supported
HT Capability overrides:
     * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
     * maximum A-MSDU length
     * supported channel width
     * short GI for 40 MHz
     * max A-MPDU length exponent
     * min MPDU start spacing
Device supports TX status socket option.
Device supports HT-IBSS.
Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
Device supports scan flush.
Device supports per-vif TX power setting
Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
Driver supports a userspace MPM
Device supports static SMPS
Device supports dynamic SMPS
```

I am getting desperate, as I am starting to think that my wifi card is broken, and I can't use my laptop with cable connection only. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of *iw list*?

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: Try disabling WiFi in the BIOS, save/reboot, and then enabling it again. If that works, I recommend a factory reset of all BIOS settings. Funky data in CMOS memory can do funny things like this...

Comment: Michael Kjorling has a good suggestion, but just to make sure we have covered all bases, I would like to check that the software is all in place: could you post the output of `lshc -C network` and of `lspci -vnn | grep -i net`. Like I said, Michael is most likely right, I just do not wish to leave any (software) stone unturned.

Comment: So I tried reseting BIOS, but then I couldn't start the system, so I did a fresh install and there is no Wireless LAN in rfkill list all and no iwlwifi package anymore.. Thanks for all help anyways

Comment: I installed the firmware-iwlwifi package, rebooted and wifi is working now. I'm not sure what the error was before, as I've proceeded same as before. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2):

Your computer does indeed have a hardware button. I think its the same as F9. Just push that button to toggle on/off WiFi and Bluetooth. (if the F-keys are set to be the top most layer you will have to hold down the fn-key while pushing the button.)

Comment: I didn't really think that was the actual button the system meant, since pushing Fn+F9 didn't work (I got an icon that network is being toggled, but the switch only had the "off" state). Reinstalling the system entirely worked for me. It seems now that the only purpose of F9 is to turn wifi OFF. This soft-blocks WLAN in rfkill, but to turn in ON, pushing again doesn't work and I have to use sw settings. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: No problems, I was in a very similar situation once with my Dell and almost went nuts, and of course felt like an idiot when i found the problem. Anyway, maybe there is a driver issue or something in your case. Or if you undo whatever sw-settings did (I'm unfamiliar with that software) the button should work like normal. With Ubuntu on my old ThinkPad all such things worked properly at least.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [fairly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180744/how-to-enable-hard-blocked-bluetooth-in-thinkpad-edge-320) [common](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2058138) [problem](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=97803) with Linux on the E320.

In my experience, the Bluetooth is hard-blocked every time you run out of battery power when suspended. If you use the machine daily, this probably won't happen, just try not to let the battery drain on standby over the long weekend.

It appears that there are two ways to get Bluetooth back:

1. **Load BIOS defaults.**
   If you're booting from EFI, this will wipe the bootloader, so you may have to have a bootable USB drive handy to restore it. The exact procedure will vary from distribution to distribution. (I use Fedora and follow the [relevant part of the Fedora documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html/Multiboot_Guide/GRUB-reinstalling.html).)
2. If you happen to have Windows installed, the Lenovo drivers for Windows can unblock the fake hardware switch.

Comment: I can confirm the issue is battery-related. It happened to me twice right after the battery drained. However, it doesn't happen always, my battery drains quite often and I haven't had this issue since I posted it here. I will give this a try if the wifi is blocked again.

Comment: Interesting. I'm fairly sure it only happens when the battery drains while suspended to ram, and I assumed it happened every time, but I may be wrong. I can't say I always know whether or not the system was switched off or on suspend when I discover that the battery has drained.

Answer (score 0):

Hard-locked e320 wifi happened here too. Wouldn't run anaymore with Ubuntu or windows. Found a simple work-around: boot the machine and go into the bios-setup. There is a section to toggle the function keys into "old-school behavior"(you don't have to press FN+function key). Now the wifi function key - or switch - is actually released and the wifi is no longer locked by the switch.